# Left Join com Dois Counts da mesma tabela

Tags: mysql

Bom pessoal, tenho um sisteminha que fiz para fazer um bolão com meus amigos. Eu quero selecionar os usuários e logo depois contar os palpites certos e os palpites errados. O banco de dados é assim (retirei as partes inúteis para facilitar):

Tabela **usuarios:**
iduser, nome

Tabela **palpites:**
iduser, idjogo, palpite, result

Há outra tabela com os jogos, mas é irrelevante aqui.

Eu fiz a seguinte query:

```
SELECT u.iduser, COUNT(p1.idpalpite) acertos, COUNT(p2.idpalpite) erros
FROM usuarios u
LEFT JOIN palpites p1 
ON u.iduser = p1.iduser
LEFT JOIN palpites p2
ON u.iduser = p2.iduser
WHERE p1.result <> '' AND p1.result = p1.palpite AND p2.result <> '' AND p2.result <> p2.palpite
GROUP BY u.iduser
```

Os resultados estão vindo assim:

```
iduser - acertos - erros
1      - 16562   - 16562
2      - 16490   - 16490
```

O certo seria a tabela voltar assim:

```
iduser - acertos - erros
1      - 170   - 97
2      - 168   - 99
```

Se eu coloco apenas um count e apenas um left join para pegar apenas os acertos, a tabela vem correta, mas quando acrescento os erros, ela vem como falei acima. O que estou fazendo errado? Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Jota use uma subconsulta (2ª à 5ª linha) para calcular o erro:

```
SELECT u.iduser, COUNT(p.idpalpite) acertos, 
(SELECT COUNT(e.idpalpite) FROM palpites e 
LEFT usuarios us
ON us.iduser = e.iduser
WHERE e.result <> '' AND e.result <> e.palpite) AS erros
FROM usuarios u
LEFT JOIN palpites p 
ON u.iduser = p.iduser
WHERE p.result <> '' AND p.result = p.palpite
GROUP BY u.iduser
```